# Modify vertices after modelview but before projection matrix is applied

Tags: opengl, graphics, rasterizing

This is for a Minecraft mod, so I'd like to keep the most of the rendering pipeline untouched.

I want to arbitrarily modify (and possibly duplicate) vertex data based on the values of all three vertices of each triangle after the modelview matrix has been applied.

Should this be done in a shader? If so, which one?

Comment: You could use custom modelview and projection matrices. Apply only the MV part in vertex shader, do what you want then apply the projection matrix and pass it on to the next stage?

Comment: You should describe which operations you actually need. Just modifying the position of vertices can be handled by a vertex shader or by modifying the input matrices used by the current shader. _Duplicating_ vertices can't be done so easily.

Comment: You could use a geometry shader. Or a tesselation shader if you're just trying to tesselate.